# Get QueryString from inside a WebControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page which contains a dynamic number of custom WebControls. What I want to do is get the containing page's query string via "Request.QueryString".

If I understand the problem correctly I need the containing page's HttpRequest object?

Is there a way to do this?

I probably should point out that I don't want to pass the QueryString from the containing page to the WebControl. I want to access the QueryString directly from the WebControl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following link:

[HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access the query string from a custom web *user control* (ascx) in the same way as you do from the page, i.e:

```
Request.QueryString...
```

From a custom control, you can either access it via:

```
Page.Request.QueryString
//or 
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString
```

BTW: the last option (`System.Web.HttpContext.Current...`) also works from any non-web-control classes (e.g. business logic).

Answer (score 0):

you can access the httpContext from anywhere using

```
HttpContext.Current
```

From there you can find the Request and the querystring

Answer (score 0):

No need to to anything in particular, Request object is directly available also to webcontrols:

```
this.Request.QueryString
```